# Sublime Text project folders : display path as name

Tags: sublimetext

I have a Sublime Text project with several folders. My problem is that these folders have the same name (the name of my app). So the folder name in the sidebar is not obvious.

For example, given a "helloworld" app :

- `d:\repos\helloworld` is my Git repository for the app.
- `d:\temp\helloworld` is a temporary folder where I extract jar files to search about a class or work on images.
- `d:\help\helloworld` is where I put some useful files like Unix commands or SQL scripts that I use to debug my app. (I share other ones in the Git repo, but these ones are private.)

So my ST sidebar is :

```
Folders
├─ helloworld
├─ helloworld
└─ helloworld
```

I know I can change my ST project file to add a name. This is what I do now:

```js
"folders": [ {
  "path": "D:\\temp\\helloworld",
  "name": "D:\\temp\\helloworld"
} ]
```

What I *want* to do is something like:

```js
"folders": [ {
  "path": "D:\\temp\\helloworld",
  "name": ${path}
} ]
```

Or with a user setting like:

```js
"use_path_as_name_in_sidebar" : true
```

Comment: Sublime text's [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=22917d1047bbf55184c87f3110abfe3d) may be a better place for feature request

Comment: Thank you. I thougt this feature exists yet and someone could help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (Sublime Text 3 Build 3059), Sublime Text's project does not support such feature.
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html

Sublime Text's [forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=4&sid=22917d1047bbf55184c87f3110abfe3d) may be a better place for such feature request.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now, and quite easy.  As per [Sublime Documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html): just edit your .project file thus:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "./path/to/your/docs",
        "name": "Documentation"
    }
]
}
```